# Changing positive numbers to negative numbers with custom number formats - and creating a script to execute this function

Tags: formatting

Looking for a means to change the positive numbers to negative with a script.

My reports have cells which will reflect the "+" sign before a number and needs to be converted to "-" sign.
Currently, I have to manually edit these cells or use the custom number format to change the value daily.
I am wondering if it would be possible to change the value of these numbers in the range?

Other note: it must only change the cells with numbers preceded with the "+"

Comment: What language is your script in?  In Javascript you could pass this value into Number.parseInt(+199) then check if it is less than 0.. and if so, multiply it by a negative 1.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks.
I will try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: Not quite sure my code is correct, using

Comment: function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('C3:C330');
  const parsed = parseInt(+199);
  if (isNaN(parsed)) { return 0; }
  return parsed * -100;
}

Comment: H.I.   "Gold (74.6/136)" "Gold/Black (73.5/134)" "Black(72.4/133)"                    +2.6              +1                            +2                           +3
It's a simple handicap report to convert a players Index to a course handicap

Comment: @rhigdon  thanks for the reply. I'm still stumbling on your method. I'm not familiar with using the parseInt(+199) function and was wondering if you would be so kind to show an example of the script. Thank you in advance for your time. Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

I took your code from the comments and tried to correct the issue:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const parsed = parseInt(sheet.getRange('C3:C330').getValue());
  if (isNaN(parsed)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return parsed * -100;
}
```

You need to pass the value of the range into the parseInt function.  -199 in my comment was just an example value.  Let me know if this makes more sense.